# Proof of pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Prove that the following function converges pointwise:
$f_n: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with 
 $f_n(x)=\dfrac{\sin{nx}}{\sqrt{n}}$

**My proof**

$f(x)=0$

Choose $x_0$ in $[0,1]$ randomly, fix $n^*=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$, then if $n>n^*$, we get:

$\left\lvert f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)\right\rvert=\left\lvert\dfrac{\sin{\left(nx_0\right)}}{\sqrt{n}}\right\rvert\leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^*}}=\epsilon$

So the function converges.

Does this hold?

Comment: It seems ok. Just be careful that, as it's been defined, $n^*$ needs not be integer (though you don't need it to be). And, perhaps, you may want to evaluate it at "$x_0$", since you took the time to pick it. But "$x$" works just fine for the name of the point.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, you're absolutely right about evaluating at $x_0$ since I introduced it for that particular job. All the proofs I've seen use the squeeze theorem which made me doubt my own proof. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: You picked the wrong $n^{\ast}$. You want $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^{\ast}}} \leqslant \epsilon$, so you must take $n^{\ast} \geqslant \dfrac{1}{\epsilon^2}$, not $\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Whooops, that was quite sloppy of me not to notice.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments:

- The choice of $n^*$ has two problems. First it should be an integer, and second this integer should be greater than $1/\varepsilon^2$ instead of $1/\sqrt\varepsilon$.
- Actually you do not choose randomly an $x_0$. You fix $x_0$ in the unit interval and work with it. There is nothing random here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|\sin(nx)|\leq 1$, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.